# Can you target xpath in pa11y?

Tags: accessibility, pa11y

Doing ADA Testing and was wondering if you can target xpath for Pa11y's actions.

For instance:
"click element *xpath*",

I only ask because there are multiple elements on the page with the same target.  No unique identifiers to tell pa11y what to click.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible to use XPath queries for [Pa11y Actions](https://github.com/pa11y/pa11y#actions) — all of them rely on CSS Selectors instead.

(Specifically, they use `document.querySelector` [under the hood](https://github.com/pa11y/pa11y/blob/master/lib/action.js#L92)).

Of course with CSS Selectors you can achieve a lot of the same things that XPath can even when there's no unique identifier available; e.g. by using sibling selectors like [`:nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-of-type).  But there is no way to select backwards up the DOM from a child selector to its parent using CSS Selectors.